# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer with the ability to record in landscape mode with Quicktime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

So I currently have a camera app. I have it so it only works in portrait mode but you can still record videos and take photos in landscape mode fine. I use the following code to handle that:

```
videoConnection?.videoOrientation = self.orientation()
```

However, since the app does not register landscape mode itself you can not record the screen via quicktime in landscape (it stays portrait) (quicktime>file>record movie>choose device name)

Is there a way to fix this? I don't need to actually change the anything about the device to support landscape, I just want the ability to be able to record it that way in quicktime but nothing in the UI needs to be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` for `UIDevice` and subscribe to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`. Afterward you can use orientation property of `UIDevice` in your code.

Reference [Apple documentation for UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications) class for details.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I am not quite sure how I would use this. Any examples?

Comment: @user2433617 Here is an answer to your request for example — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` for `UIDevice` and subscribe it to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

Use oreintation proporty of `UIDevice`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to detect the change in orientation:

Check this apple documentation [UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications), for more details about that.

Here is a sample implemention in 
[Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902054/quick-180-rotation-of-ios-device-results-in-the-camera-viewing-upside-down/31016799#31016799) &&
[Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing! Making use of the marked answer.

```
func orientationChanged() {
    var orient = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    if orient == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
        print("PORT")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
    } else if orient == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft {
        print("OR ARE YOU CRASHING")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight
    } else if orient == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight {
        print("WHY YOU CRASHING")
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
    } else if orient == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
    }
```